# array defult value insert not proper insert data?

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

I am using CodeIgniter insert array value issue first array value insert fine but multiple value not insert proper so please share valuable idea sir. i am share all issue code here...

**CodeIgniter models**

```
  public function savemedicine()
        {
            $db2 = $this->load->database('dpr',TRUE);

            $medicine_typer = array("CAB", "TAB", "CAB","CAB");
            $pricer = array("202", "100", "97","92");
            $quantityr = array("2","2","1","3");
           
    
           foreach ($item_namer as $key => $value){
    
                  //print_r($medicine_typer[$key]);//output CABA
                  //print_r($quantityr[$key]);//output 2
                  //print_r($pricer[$key]);//output 2020
    
                $medicine_typer         =$medicine_typer[$key];
                $quantityr              =$quantityr[$key];
                $pricer                 =$pricer[$key];
            
        $db2->query('INSERT INTO dpr_medicine_return(medicine_type,quantity,price)
            VALUES ("'.$medicine_typer.'","'.$quantityr.'","'.$pricer.'")');
                
             $i++;       
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> you are revaluing variable in the loop so when the loop run for 2 time the
> time it didn't find those array variable but now they are not  array
> use this code

```
$medicine_typer2         =$medicine_typer[$key];            
    $quantityr2              =$quantityr[$key];   
    $pricer2                =$pricer[$key];            
    $itemidr2               =$item_idr[$key];
```

> now use these variable in your query

Comment: thanu so much sir for share valuable idea

Comment: @Amitabh kumar your problem is solved or not??